# Cloudfoundry Error 310 : Staging failed : Staging plugin failed

Tags: cloud-foundry

CFoundry::AppStagingError: 310: Staging failed: 'Staging task failed:
 Staging plugin failed: /var/vcap/packages/stager/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/
vcap_staging-0.1.63/lib/vcap/staging/plugin/java_web/plugin.rb:28:in `block in s
tage_application': Web application staging failed: web.xml not found (RuntimeErr
or)
        from /var/vcap/packages/stager/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/vcap_stagin
g-0.1.63/lib/vcap/staging/plugin/java_web/plugin.rb:22:in`chdir'
        from /var/vcap/packages/stager/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/vcap_stagin
g-0.1.63/lib/vcap/staging/plugin/java_web/plugin.rb:22:in `stage_application'
        from /var/vcap/packages/stager/bin/run_plugin:19:in`'
'
For more information, see ~/.vmc/crash

This is the error i'm getting whenever i run the vmc push command when trying to deploy any java files or .war files in windows. After running this command, i can see that the file is uploaded on the cloud but it never runs correctly. I experience almost the same error when i try to run through java/spring or any other framework.

Someone please help me with this issue.

Comment: Do you use the --path switch to specify the location of your war file when you push the app?